# Split a string into an array in C++

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

I have an input file of data and each line is an entry. in each line each "field" is seperated by a white space " " so I need to split the line by space. other languages have a function called split (C#, PHP etc) but I cant find one for C++. How can I achieve this? Here is my code that gets the lines:

```
string line;
ifstream in(file);

while(getline(in, line)){

  // Here I would like to split each line and put them into an array

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>  //for std::istringstream
#include <iterator> //for std::istream_iterator
#include <vector>   //for std::vector

while(std::getline(in, line))
{
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss), end;

    //putting all the tokens in the vector
    std::vector<std::string> arrayTokens(begin, end); 

    //arrayTokens is containing all the tokens - use it!
}
```

By the way, use qualified-names such as `std::getline`, `std::ifstream` like I did. It seems you've written `using namespace std` somewhere in your code which is considered a bad practice. So don't do that:

- [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a discussion on why it is a bad practise to use `using namespace x`?

Comment: @jli: Added the link to my answer. See it.

Comment: @Nawaz thanks, Looking at my other questions, the syntax I am using and the way I am learning C++ from my instructors at uni is highly questionable :S!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<string> v;
boost::split(v, line, ::isspace);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3115768

Answer (score 5):

I have written a function for a similar requirement of mine,
maybe you can use it!

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) 
{
    std::stringstream ss(s+' ');
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) 
    {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). Look for it in the C++ reference:.

Comment: `strtok` is a C library thing, whereas the poster is asking for how to do it correctly with C++.

Comment: and c++ is not c?(... OMG all those years they all lied to me :D). Since when c library have stopped working in c++(or turned incorrect)?

Comment: If you mix them, you add unnecessary dependances, among other issues.

Comment: A link to the issues and DEPENDENCIES involved in using c in c++ please? ...I mean for all those years of wrongly compiling and using c code and libraries in c++ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025869/using-mixing-c-in-c-code I guess the dependencies is not really the issue, but imo doing something like `#include <iostream>` `#include <cstdio>` gets redundant.

Comment: Also I just realized I spelled dependencies wrong in my second comment (damn phone soft keyboards).

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses `strtok()` to split a  string into tokens and stores the tokens in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


char one_line_string[] = "hello hi how are you nice weather we are having ok then bye";
char seps[]   = " ,\t\n";
char *token;



int main()
{
   vector<string> vec_String_Lines;
   token = strtok( one_line_string, seps );

   cout << "Extracting and storing data in a vector..\n\n\n";

   while( token != NULL )
   {
      vec_String_Lines.push_back(token);
      token = strtok( NULL, seps );
   }
     cout << "Displaying end result in  vector line storage..\n\n";

    for ( int i = 0; i < vec_String_Lines.size(); ++i)
    cout << vec_String_Lines[i] << "\n";
    cout << "\n\n\n";


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is best used with the almost-standard-library boost.

And an example : 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3115768

Answer (score 0):

Either use a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) or read token by token from your `ifstream`.

To do it with a stringstream:

```
string line, token;
ifstream in(file);

while(getline(in, line))
{
    stringstream s(line);
    while (s >> token)
    {
        // save token to your array by value
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you could use boost if you so desire, or another STL function to do the copying out of the stringstream.

Comment: If the input ends in whitespace, this inner while-loop generates an additional empty token in the end. The idiomatic C++ `while(s >> token)` does not.

Comment: This is true. May as well edit to use that method.