# split a sentence so that adds each word in an array item

Tags: c++, arrays, split

I have a sentence, I want split the sentence so that adds each word in an array item.
I have done the following code but it still wrong.

```
string str = "Welcome to the computer world.";
string strWords[5];
short counter = 0;
for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    strWords[counter] = str[i];
    if(str[i] == ' '){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448176/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-c

Comment: @Cyber: My question is slightly different from the questions that you think that my question is similar to them.

Comment: I doubt it. You want to split a string on spaces. You happened to want to add them to an array, but the easier, safer, and more extensible solution would be using a stream to parse it into a `vector`.

Comment: Here is my solution with plain C++ code and no fancy functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58797347/8209106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering since you should learn from your mistakes: just use the `+=` string operator and your code will work:

```
// strWords[counter] = str[i];   <- change this
strWords[counter] += str[i];     <- to this
```

to remove the spaces (if you don't want to append them) just change the order of the space check, something like:

```
for (short i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){
    if (str[i] == ' ')
        counter++;
    else
        strWords[counter] += str[i];
}
```

anyway I'm suggesting to use the duplicate link [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) too

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the simplest answer.

Comment: @LionKing are you aware that you will still have the spaces in the sentence appended to each word since you check for space only after you've added the character to the current word?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Thanks for your tip. but I don't see any space with each word.

Comment: @LionKing It is not a tip:D If you changed nothing else in your code rather than the append you have a space as the last element in each string in your `strWords`. Look at the example in my answer.

Comment: @MarcoA. well my comment was not meant as an offense to the answer but more as a hint for the author to understand the algorithm he has written:)

Comment: None taken! I understand

Answer (score 2):

Very ugly way to do it, @Cyber has linked to the best answer. But here's your "corrected" version:

```
string str = "Welcome to the computer world.";
string strWords[5];
short counter = 0;

for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(str[i] == ' '){
        counter++;
        i++;
    }
    strWords[counter] += str[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a lot of more convenient ways to split a string (`strtok`, std functionality, etc.), but if we talk about your sample, you should not assign the 'str[i]' but append it, since it is a single character that you want to append to the current word like this:

```
string str = "Welcome to the computer world.";
string strWords[5];
short counter = 0;
for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(str[i] == ' ' && !strWords[counter].empty()){
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        strWords[counter] += str[i];
    }
}
```

But this will work only on the given input data, since you can access the array `strWords` outside bounds if  you have more than five words. Consider using a following code:

```
string str = "Welcome to the computer world.";
vector<string> strWords;
string currentWord;
for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(str[i] == ' ' && !currentWord.empty()){
       strWords.push_back(currentWord);
       currentWord.clear();
    }
    else {
        currentWord += str[i];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since I assume you are new to C++, here is the demonstration of the space issue you have (if you only use the addition operator):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string str = "Welcome to the computer world.";
    string strWords[5];
    short counter = 0;
    for(short i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        strWords[counter] += str[i]; // Append fixed
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for(short i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout << strWords[i] << "(" << strWords[i].size() << ")" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image: Space at the end of each string]