# C++, function to return array as string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I am new to C++ and am trying to make a function that takes an array of numbers and converts those numbers into the ASCII character, i.e. int to string. When I try to output the string however I get random characters. I have searched tutorials and a suggestion was that I should add a string terminator, which I did, but it doesn't seem to fix it and I can't find an answer that would solve this.

i.e. I want the below code to print "Hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char* intToString(int* array, int size)
{
    char string[size + 1];
    string[size] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        string[i] = array[i];

    return string;
}


int main()
{
    int my_array[5] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111};
    int size = 5;
    std::cout << intToString(my_array, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're missing something along the lines of `string[i] = itoa(array[i]);` since the random characters you get aren't the character representation of the numbers you want.

Comment: You include `#include <string>` but don't use `std::string` (C++ string).

Comment: In your code it should be `i<size` since `array[size]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As close as possible to your initial attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string intToString(int my_array[], int size)
{
    // just declare a variable of type std::string instead of char string[size+1]
    // there's no need to define a size as this std::string will grow dynamically
    // there's also no need to add a delimiter as std::string takes 
    // care of this itself
    std::string string;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // this appends an integer representing an (ASCII) codepoint 
        // to an initially empty std::string
        string += my_array[i];
        // this won't work as string is initially empty
        // so you can't access the element at index 0 
        // string[i] = my_array[i];
    }
    return string;
}
int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    int my_array[] = { 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 };
    std::cout << intToString(my_array, size) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the differences to your solution pointed out in the comments.

Comment: While it's technically true that the buffer managed by a `std::string` is going to be terminated by a `'\0'` (because this is the only decent way to implement it given the requirements of `op[]`), instead of saying "[string] takes care of [the delimiter] itself" it's more logically correct to say "string doesn't have a delimiter because it tracks content length separately".

Answer (score 1):

`char *` is not a string. It's a pointer to `char`. In your case you get random characters because you return pointer to local `string` which is destroyed after the call. Use `std::string` or, if you want arrays that much, you can get proper copy semantics from `std::array`.

Comment: My "string terminator" was useless too, so I removed that. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewCina: No, you needed that for the `<<`. Unfortunately you implemented it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't even compile because size+1 isn't a compile time constant value, changing the line

```
char string[size+1];
```

to

```
char string*=new char[size+1]
```

should make your code compile and give correct output because you create your array on the heap (so the array is not destroyed when the function returns). However that means that you have to <s>destroy</s> delete it yourself.

So it's a good idea to change

```
std::cout << intToString(my_array, size);
```

To

```
char *string=intToString(my_array, size);
std::cout << string;
delete[] string;
```

Though note that others answers are right that you should use std::string and std::vector instead of char arrays and arrays in general, what you're doing right now is mixing c with c++.

Comment: Thanks, is there more information somewhere on not mixing c with c++? I don't fully understand the taboo I've broken with mixing them.

Comment: One of the primary design goals of C++ is its compatibility with C. This means that as a developer you have to decide when  to use C types like plain arrays or C++ (better: STL) types like `std::vector`. For example if you are developing in C++ for certain microcontroller architectures it can even be forbidden to use any of the STL types like `std::vector` or `std::string` as there is no dynamic heap memory and/or the performance of these types does not meet the very strict requirements in these areas. Hence the choice of types and therefore style does very much depend on your environment.

Comment: I recommend this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025869/using-mixing-c-in-c-code) in general there's not much wrong with it but for beginners it's better to either grasp C or C++. because std::string is not the same as char[] so if you use one function with char array and second with std string  you're going to have a bad time. Later on you might mix C with C++ when you get familiar enough with C++.

Comment: Thanks both - I looked at that question and it’s definitly useful, but, not to go off topic too much, when am I actually using c in c++? When I’m trying to write code that can be handled easier by the STL? For example, as far as any tutorial on c++ that I’ve done shows, arrays appear to be fair game. Hope that makes sense and isn’t a bad question.

Comment: @AndrewCina Arrays certainly have their uses in c++, if you want a chess board for example it's better to use an array int a[8][8] then to use a vector. I don't think you should focus that much on it really.

Comment: @AndrewCina When you write code in C++ without making use of the STL or polymorphism or templates then your program will most probably resemble a C program. As has been stated above there can be good reasons to do so, so you won't break any taboo.

Answer (score 0):

There is still a problem in the **updated** solution that you have written.

- You should still declare the `string` array with `size+1` and need to make the last element as `\0`.
- Or you can use the `std::string`.

Here is C++ way of doing it, it can be further shortened, but this is as close as it can get to your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string intToString(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::string ans;
    for (auto& each : vec)
        ans += char(each);
    return ans;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{72, 101, 108, 108, 111};
    std::cout << intToString(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some new language for me to explore there - thank you. So I understand correctly that my code (not shortened) would be corrected by just declaring the string with std::string instead of char? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Its not enough to just declare `string` of type `std::string`. See my answer.

Comment: As I have mentioned, you can use `char[size+1]`, but it's working by chance in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 `std::to_string` is preferable. If you need your converter function for more than one type and/or datacontainer you can use a template function like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
std::string toString(const T & items) {
    std::string str;
    for (const auto & item : items) {
        str += std::to_string(item);
    }

    return str;
}


int main() {
    const std::vector<int> my_vector {102, 101, 108, 108, 111};
    std::cout << toString(my_vector);


    std::cout << std::endl;

    const std::array<double,5> my_array {102, 101, 108, 108.5, 111.0};
    std::cout << toString(my_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question's author specified that he want to convert ints to corresponding ascii chars not their string representation.