# Including a .c file in a c++ program

Tags: c++, c

I am working on a project where half my code is in c and half is in c++.

Now I want to include the cprogram.c in my cppprogram.cpp.

When including a c file inside a c program you can use

```
#include "cprogram.c"
```

Anyways to do that in c++ for including a c program.

Comment: You should never #include a *.c file.  Doing it across languages is even worse.

Comment: You can do that, if and only if the code in that file can be compiled as C++ (the compiler doesn't care about the `.c` extension). So, in other words, it must be valid C++ as well.  However, normally you don't mix things like that and if you mix C and C++ you compile them separately. All that said, you don't ask a question. Please, as a new user here, start with the  [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: *"When including a c file inside a c program"* - that's *not* how one normally includes a .c file in a C program. It is normally part of the compile source files list that are individually built, usually as part of a build pattern such as a Makefile, a CMakeLists.txt, a visual studio project file, etc. And `#include`-ing a .c file in a c++ source file (.cpp/.cxx) is at best a gamble. C and C++ are different languages. There is a *chance* it will "work" (term used very loosely). You're probably better off incorporating the file properly as a C source, compiled as C target in your build system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides from that you normally [don't include `.c` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002266/why-we-should-not-include-source-files-in-c/31008353#31008353), but `.h` files instead, and that the following is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025869/using-mixing-c-in-c-code), you can include C files into `.cpp` / `.hpp` files by wrapping the include into an `extern "C"`:

#### cppprogram.cpp

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include "cprogram.c"
}
```

See [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using Make or Cmake, you can just add it with `#include "cprogram.c"`. C++ is also compatiable with C so you can just add it.